# MS-Word(Mac) Type Case Macro - Fixing abbreviations with specific capitalized letters

Tags: vba, ms-word, typecase

I am trying to tweak/add to a type case macro I made and have been working on that I use in MS-Word (mac).  I am trying to add to the macro to recognize specific abbreviations and convert them to a specific type case.  For example, converting "ml" or "Ml" or "ML" to mL.  Converting "gm" or "Gm" or "GM" to g.

I have attached my code below of what I have so far that fixes/ignores capitalizations, I just need help adding in these new rules.  I am guessing I would have to create a bunch of specific If/Then statements, but I am not exactly sure.

```
Sub CaseFix()
'
' CaseFix Macro
'
'
Dim lclist As String
    Dim wrd As Integer
    Dim sTest As String

    ' list of lowercase words, surrounded by spaces
    lclist = " of or the by your to this into at but with on compare compared is in for from a an and cm min minutes minute sec seconds mL gm g "

    Selection.Range.Case = wdTitleWord

    For wrd = 2 To Selection.Range.Words.Count
        sTest = Trim(Selection.Range.Words(wrd))
        sTest = " " & LCase(sTest) & " "
        If InStr(lclist, sTest) Then
            Selection.Range.Words(wrd).Case = wdLowerCase
        End If
    Next wrd
End Sub
```

Comment: No need for a macro to do that. Just [Add or remove AutoCorrect entries in Word](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-or-remove-autocorrect-entries-in-word-e7433b94-f3de-4532-9dc8-b29063a96e1f). This feature is already built in (replace as you type).

Comment: Are you trying to do this after a document has already been created? In other words, performing this in some post edit process? If you are trying to do this at the time of document creation, then @Pᴇʜ has provided you with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For an existing document:

```
Sub CaseFix()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim FList As String, RList As String, j As Long
FList = "aaa,aba,aca,ada"
RList = "AAa,aBa,ACA,AdA"
With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
  .ClearFormatting
  .Replacement.ClearFormatting
  .Format = False
  .Forward = True
  .MatchWholeWord = True
  .MatchWildcards = False
   'Process each word from the Find/Replace Lists
  For j = 0 To UBound(Split(FList, ","))
    .Text = UCase(Split(FList, ",")(j))
    .Replacement.Text = Split(RList, ",")(j)
    .MatchCase = False
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .MatchCase = True
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  Next
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Note that you must have the same number of comma-separated entries in the FList and RList.